# Unexpected behaviour of ListEntry's state after dismission

Tags: flutter

On a page I have ListView with ListEntry`s elements.
ListEntry is a statefull and have a property _visible, which is false by default.
There is a method _onLeadingPressed which allows invert _visible property - there's no problems with it.
Every ListEntry is Dismissible, so I can dismiss it.

```
class ListEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListEntryState createState() => _ListEntryState();
}

class _ListEntryState extends State<ListEntry> {
  bool _visible = false;

  // there is an option to change `_visible` for every `ListEntry`
  void _onLeadingPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _visible = !_visible;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
      onDismissed: (direction) async {
        _visible = false;
        // some action here
      },
      child: ListTile(
        //every ListTile has a logic to show some info based on `_visible` value
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And now the interesting part.
For example, a current ListView contains these elements:

- ListEntry 1 (_visible = false)
- ListEntry 2 (_visible = true)
- ListEntry 3 (_visible = false)

Let's dismiss ListEntry 1. Now the ListView appears as this:

- ListEntry 2 (_visible = false)
- ListEntry 3 (_visible = true)

Why then ListEntry 3 has true and ListEntry 2 also cnanged to false?
Is not it should be like this after dismiss first element?

- ListEntry 2 (_visible = true)
- ListEntry 3 (_visible = false)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're facing is with the keys. When you call `setState`, new unique key will be generated and assigned to the ListEntry and flutter cannot find any widget with that key in its element tree so that's why you may get this behaviour.

Try using something that's specific to that ListEntry as a key like a name, title or anything that's specific to the ListEntry so when you call `setState`, you don't generate a new uniqueKey but you use the previous one and Flutter can find the matching state to the widget with the same key. That should keep the state as before and show the correct values.

Checkout [this](https://youtu.be/TiCA0CEePyE?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIK0r_D-zWcmJ1plIcDNnRkK&t=128) part of the Flutter Boring Show that has the same kind of problem and also [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers).